# Can anyone guide me through the steps about embeding libvlc in my android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libvlc

This may look like a duplicate question, but all the previous answers were too much confusing for a ameature developer like me. I have never used NDK before and I am working with android studio and windows PC. Previous answers(1,2) and other sources are suggesting to use linux to compile. I couldn't understand what to do. Can anyone guide me through the steps about embeding libvlc in my android app

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble with compiling vlc , then you can use the following library , thou it is unofficial , but I worked with it and it worked fine .

[Unofficial VLC Android SDK](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk)

Comment: I am getting "Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12." By using "implementation 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar' "

Comment: share your gradle file

Comment: Thanks.I thought all of this was happening for some out dated code. Turns out it was not. I was putting the lines on build.gradle (module) instead of build.gradle(project) file. Thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10, you should be able to follow the wiki at https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ using WSL (and google/use the videolan forum for what you don't know).

If you don't want to compile, another way could be to [download the apk of the official vlc-android app](https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc-android/3.0.9/), unzip it, extract the libs you want (namely `libvlcjni.so` and probably `libjniloader.so`) and add it to your project (which means making gradle happy).

[vlc-android](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android) is a fully opensource app that does exactly what you want to do. Feel free to have a look.

Good luck